# Ubuntu's partition not recognized?

Tags: grub2, partitioning

***PLEASE MAKE SURE YOU READ EVERYTHING***: most people post answers that are literally out of context, which is frustrating!

I am in big trouble right now. My Ubuntu partition is not recognized and therefore cannot be used. As a result, whenever my computer boots up, it shows a "grub-rescue" black screen, which is annoying.

I am currently running a Debian live DVD. I will neither re-insall anything nor format the Ubuntu partition because I think this is a problem that can be resolved.

What happened the moment before I get this GRUB-RESCUE screen? I was working on Ubuntu and decided to create a new partition for my data, labeled "DONNEES" (french of "data"). This computer literally froze... and after 30 minutes, I was very 'angry' and I forced the shutdown of the computer (since the mouse wasn't moving). Now, I can't access anything but every live CD and DVD I have created. Unfortunately, I was running Ubuntu 14.04 and I have a live DVD with 13.10.

So my question is: since I have approx. 150 GB of data on Ubuntu that is currently unreadable, will I (eventually) be able to get my partition back? Or should I just sit in a corner and cry?

Here are a couple of screenshots that will probably help, directly taken from my Debian live DVD.

[image: A general overview]

[image: A couple of details]

Comment: Use GRUB-Rescue.  But prepare for the fact of you may not recover it.

Comment: I have never used grub-rescue before. I'd like to know if you can gve me some tips regarding grub-rescue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If sda1 is ext family formatted:

From liveDVD/Flash so everything is unmounted,swap off if necessary, change example shown with partition sda1 to your partition(s)
e2fsck is used to check the ext2/ext3/ext4 family of file systems. -p trys fixes where response not required

```
sudo e2fsck -C0 -p -f -v /dev/sda1
```

if errors: -y auto answers yes for fixes needing response, also see man e2fsck

```
sudo e2fsck -f -y -v /dev/sda1
```

And never shutdown system except as last case. Remember the Elephants:

Holding down Alt and SysRq (which is the Print Screen key) while slowly typing REISUB

R-E-I-S-U-B to force shutdown

A good way to remember it is.
Raising Skinny Elephants Is Utterly Boring ...or
Reboot System Even If Ultimately Broken ...

Check for backup super blocks:

```
sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda1 | grep -i backup
```

This is a last ditch suggestion if no one else has better suggestions:

```
sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda1 | grep "block size" -i
```

You must use the above number like

```
Block size:               4096
```

Then reformat just the superblocks:
See  -S setting or briefly

-S    Write  superblock and group descriptors only.:

```
man mke2fs
```

Then only using the block size you get or else you have further damage:

```
sudo mke2fs -S -b 4096 -v /dev/sda1
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried these command lines at home earlier today. I said for the first command that there was not ext2 partition and though it was corrupted. Same thing was said for the second command. It there any way of repararing a corrupted ext partition? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure sda1 is your Linux partition and not a NTFS partition and sda5 is your Linux partition? If NTFS then you have to use chkdsk from a Windows repairCD or flash drive. Or if other Linux formats that are not ext, then you have to use tools for those formats. If really ext4, see if you can view other superblocks  sudo dumpe2fs /dev/sda1 | grep -i backup

Comment: Yes, whenever I install a version of Linux of any laptop I am using, I use the ext4 partition type, every time. When I ran the command with dumpe2fs, it gave me: <dumpe2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda1>

Comment: See above for last ditch superblock reformat. Otherwise photorec which is a long arduous process.